# Group rows based on column values in SQL / BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to "group" rows within BigQuery/SQL depending on column values? Let's say I want to assign a string/id for all rows between stream_start_init and stream_start and then do the same for the rows between stream_resume and the last stream_ad.

The amount of stream_ad event can differ hence I can't use a RANK() or ROW() to group them be based on those values.

```
|id, timestamp, event|
|1 |  1231231 | first_visit|
|2 |  1231232 | login|
|3 |  1231233 | page_view|
|4 |  1231234 | page_view| 
|5 |  1231235 | stream_start_init|
|6 |  1231236 | stream_ad|
|7 |  1231237 | stream_ad| 
|8 |  1231238 | stream_ad| 
|9 |  1231239 | stream_start|
|6 |  1231216 | stream_resume|
|6 |  1231236 | stream_ad|
|7 |  1231217 | stream_ad| 
|8 |  1231258 | stream_ad| 
|10|  1231240 | page_view|
```

How I wish the table to be

```
|id, timestamp, event, group_id|
|1 |  1231231 | first_visit, null|
|2 |  1231232 | login, null|
|3 |  1231233 | page_view, null|
|4 |  1231234 | page_view, null| 
|5 |  1231235 | stream_start_init, group_1|
|6 |  1231236 | stream_ad, group_1|
|7 |  1231237 | stream_ad, group_1| 
|8 |  1231238 | stream_ad, group_1| 
|9 |  1231239 | stream_start, group_1|
|6 |  1231216 | stream_resume, group_2|
|6 |  1231236 | stream_ad, group_2|
|7 |  1231217 | stream_ad, group_2| 
|8 |  1231258 | stream_ad, group_2| 
|10|  1231240 | page_view, null|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't assign a string.  I would assign a number.  This appears to be a cumulative sum.  I think a sum of the number of "stream_start_init" and "stream_resume" does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       countif(event in ('stream_start_init', 'stream_resume')) over (order by timestamp) as group_id
from t;
```

Note that this produces `0` for the first group -- which seems like a good thing.  You can convert that to a `NULL` using `NULLIF()`.

If you really want strings, you can use `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thanks a lot! I had no idea that you could use the "x IN () " to achieve this, great insight!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  IF(event IN ('stream_start_init', 'stream_start', 'stream_resume', 'stream_ad'),
    COUNTIF(event IN ('stream_start_init', 'stream_resume')) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp),
    NULL
  ) AS group_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```